# Are NHibernate 3 future queries compatible with AliasToBeanResultTransformer

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 3 on a project and have a requirement to call two stored procedures and return the results in a DTO structure.  For performance reasons I have used Future queries e.g.

```
            var contractstaffroles = GetSession()
                .CreateSQLQuery(string.Format("exec up_List_ContractStaffRole_By_Staff @staffId = :staffId"))
                .SetParameter("staffId", staffId)
                .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(ContractStaffRoleReadOnlyData)))
                .Future<ContractStaffRoleReadOnlyData>().ToList();

            var contractstaffroleperiods = GetSession()
                .CreateSQLQuery(string.Format("exec up_List_ContractStaffRolePeriods_By_Staff @staffId = :staffId"))
                .SetParameter("staffId", staffId)
                .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof (ContractStaffRolePeriodReadOnlyData)))
                .Future<ContractStaffRolePeriodReadOnlyData>().ToList();

var cnt = contractstaffroles.Count();
```

The first query is correctly returning records from the stored procedure.  However, the resulting DTOs are empty i.e no property setters have been set.  When I remove the Future key words the DTOs are correctly populated...but this results in two calls to the database on two connections.  So is it not possible to use future queries with transformers in Nhibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug in JIRA (3222)](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3222). It had been reported by [Bryan Pedlar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216627/bryan-pedlar) after asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513240/nhibernate-future-query-with-resultsettransformer) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Many thanks.  I wonder when they will fix it.  It was reported in December 2012.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not fixed even with NH 3.3.3.4000 :(